# What are the cases in which $this from a custom theme's template does not recognize the theme's appropriate block?

Tags: php, blocks, ce-1.9.1.0, product-view

Pardon me for my lack of Magento knowledge in advance. I'm adding custom functionality to a theme like this:

*app/code/local/Myvendor/Mymodule/Block/Catalog/Product/View.php*:

```
class Myvendor_Mymodule_Block_Catalog_Product_View extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View
{
  public function myCustomFunction() {
    // Custom functionality
  }
}
```

This function is called in a template like this:

> app/design/frontend/myvendor_mymodule/default/template/catalog/product/view/options/wrapper.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->myCustomFunction(); ?>
```

However, in Xdebug, $this always points to `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View`

What are the cases in which the custom module's block is not recognized, and $this defaults to the Mage block instead?

- The custom module is active at *app/etc/modules/Myvendor_Mymodule.xml*
- The custom block is specified at *app/code/local/Myvendor/Mymodule/etc/config.xml*:

  `<blocks>
  <myvendor_mymodule>
      <class>Myvendor_Mymodule_Block</class>
  </myvendor_mymodule>
  </blocks>`
- The public function name does not conflict with any other function names.
- It's necessary for the template to be located inside the `myvendor_mymodule` package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to **rewrite** `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View`  class, then you can use this way

```
<?php echo $this->myCustomFunction(); ?>
```

```
<blocks>
    <myvendor_mymodule>
        <class>Myvendor_Mymodule_Block</class>
    </myvendor_mymodule>
    <catalog>
        <rewrite>
            <product_view>Myvendor_Mymodule_Block_Catalog_Product_View</product_view>
        </rewrite>
    </catalog>
</blocks>
```

Clear cache.

Comment: Quick answer and fully working solution. Very much appreciated!